# How to import and use packages of osgi bundles in wso2 api manager

Tags: maven, jar, wso2, osgi

I ask you about how to import packages of osgi bundles in wso2 api manager.
well, I know that if I want to use external jar library, I have to convert jar file to OSGi bundle. so I converted a jar and copy in a folder at CARBON_HOME/components/dropins.
also I confirmed that the converted osgi bundle is active.
but, I don't know how to use that source in the osgi bundle.

Please tell me about a way to use source code and packages of the osgi bundle in wso2 api manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the custom code, you need to extent API Manager classes. [Here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Writing+Custom+Handlers) is how you can write a custom handler for API Manager. You can write anything you need in APIM even new transports.